# How to perform a query inside a realm migration?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm moving a field from linked object to a non calculated field

```
public dynamic var venue: Venue!
```

Now I need to create a migration to populate this field that before this change was calculated using `linkedobjects`

My migration is like this

```
if (oldSchemaVersion < 7) {
    migration.enumerate(VenueRoom.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
        let venue = try! Realm().objects(Venue).filter("ANY venueRooms.id = %@", oldObject!["id"]!).first
        newObject!["venue"] = venue
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work with the following error

> "Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 6." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Provided schema version 0 is less than last set version 6.}:

What seems to make sense

Then I try the following approach to get a realm instance with the correct configuration

```
if (oldSchemaVersion < 7) {
    migration.enumerate(VenueRoom.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
        let configuration = Realm.Configuration(
            schemaVersion: self.schemaVersion,
            migrationBlock: nil
        )
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)

        let venue = realm.objects(Venue).filter("ANY venueRooms.id = %@", oldObject!["id"]!).first
        newObject!["venue"] = venue
    }
}
```

But it gets stuck on

```
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

It never comes back from that statement, no error.

What's the correct way to perform a query inside a migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing a query within a migration block is [not currently supported](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1385). Until support is added you'll want to use `Migration.enumerate(_:_:)` to enumerate objects of a given type and perform any filtering you need in Swift.

Comment: Yes, you can use `Migration.deleteData(_:)` to delete all objects of a given class.